# Do proximity alerts need coordinates updates from my app?

Tags: android, location, alert, updates, proximity

I am working on an app that would use proximity alerts to trigger some functionality. I have dug into some tutorials and examples, setup some alerts, it seems to work somewhat okay. However when I closed the app, (I call locationManager.removeUpdates() to no longer receive updates), it seemed that alerts kept coming.

So my question is, do I actually need to provide gps fix to the alarm api? Or does the system obtain it on its own and I dont need to worry about it, unless creating a new one, where you need those coords?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using a broadcast reciever, i think if you unregister broadcast reciever the alerts will stop

Comment: is that the question, why dont the alerts stop?

Comment: well I have a static receiver registered in the manifest, the question is wether does my activity have to do locationManager.requestLocationUpdates to have the alerts fired? Because the alerts keep comming even tho the activity is destroyed

Comment: oh, im not sure about that, i know that if you have reciever in code which is pretty much the same you have to call unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast); i dont think you have to call requestLocationUpdates, the broadcastreciever does it with pending intents

Comment: ill put my code up for you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to use request location updates - you just unregister your receiver to stop the alerts

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ProximityService extends Service {

    String proximitysd = "com.apps.ProximityService";
    int n = 0;
    private BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public ProximityService() {}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mybroadcast = new ProximityIntentReceiver();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        double lat;
        double lng;
        float radius = 50f;
        long expiration = -1;
        MyDBAdapter db = new MyDBAdapter(this);
        Cursor cursor;
        db.read();
        cursor = db.getAllEntries();
        boolean go = cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() != true) {
            lat = cursor.getInt(MyDBAdapter.LATITUDE_COLUMN) / 1E6;
            lng = cursor.getInt(MyDBAdapter.LONGITUDE_COLUMN) / 1E6;
            String what = cursor.getString(MyDBAdapter.ICON_COLUMN);
            String how = cursor.getString(MyDBAdapter.TYPE_COLUMN);
            String proximitys = "com.apps.ProximityService" + n;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(proximitys);
            registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);
            Intent intent = new Intent(proximitys);
            intent.putExtra("alert", what);
            intent.putExtra("type", how);
            PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, n,
                    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            locationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, lng, radius, expiration,
                    proximityIntent);
            // sendBroadcast(new Intent(intent));
            n++;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Proximity Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Proximity Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        // IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(proximitys);
        // registerReceiver(mybroadcast,filter);
    }

    public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
            Boolean entering = arg1.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
            String here = arg1.getExtras().getString("alert");
            String happy = arg1.getExtras().getString("type");
            if (entering) {
            }
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
                    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0,
                    arg1, 0);
            Notification notification = createNotification();
            notification
                    .setLatestEventInfo(arg0, "Proximity Alert!",
                            "You are approaching a " + here + " marker.",
                            pendingIntent);
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }

        private Notification createNotification() {
            Notification notification = new Notification();
            notification.icon = R.drawable.icon;
            notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
            notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
            notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
            notification.ledOffMS = 1500;
            return notification;
        }
        // make actions
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is not really how to stop them, I was just surprised that they didnt stop even though my app no longer receives gsp updates and the alarms were still firing, so I just didnt know wether its a bug or feature :-D

Comment: yeah i think that the broadcast reciever gets its own location updates for proximity alerts